# why Alt+F2 r didnt work on gnome shell classic

Tags: 12.04, gnome-classic

Im using gnome shell classic on ubuntu 12.04.
However, i notice that tht (ALT + F2 + r) didnt work. How do i get this effect on gnome shell classic? I just want to restart shell without logging out.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Alt-F2 has always been the run menu in Gnome, and r would be the program to run, which is exactly what is happening, and is exactly what has always happened for me in the past.  Why did you expect something different?  Also, you can't restart the shell (or X windows) without the need to log back in.  Perhaps you mean something else besides "the shell".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `killall gnome-panel`

- You can assign that to a keyboard shortcut if you want, it will restart the gnome panel.
- There's no "classic shell", by the way, only the gnome-panel.