# Restore Alt+F2 "program execute" in GNOME Classic (no effects)

Tags: gnome-panel, gnome-classic

I dislike Unity so I use 12.04 in GNOME Classic (no effects) mode.

ALT+F2 is not bringing up the usual "execute binary..." dialog box.

How can I restore that?

I have browsed around (e.g. [why Alt+F2 r didnt work on gnome shell classic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189522/why-altf2-r-didnt-work-on-gnome-shell-classic)) but solutions like `killall gnome-panel` etc don't cut it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In System Settings - Hardware - Keyboard - Shortcuts tab, click `System` - `Show the run command prompt` - Alt+F2, change it if it's disabled or set to something else.

CCSM can also set this in "GNOME Compatibility".

Comment: Cool, good to see it works;-)